# Traceback Error when i try to use Texture Atlas for a group of objects

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

In my current Model, I already have 4 texture pages and I am currently packing for the 5th one. I found some errors in the modelling. I had deleted some instances and tried to continue packing using texture atlas.

I forgot to delete the old group and create a new one instead because i had deleted some objects. So whenever I try to hit 'Start Manual Unwrap'. I get the following Error for the Texture Atlas Add-on.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programs\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\uv_texture_atlas.py", line 224, in execute
    group_name=group.name, resolutionX=resX, resolutionY=resY)
  File "D:\Programs\Blender\2.79\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 189, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programs\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\uv_texture_atlas.py", line 575, in execute
    tex.name = self.group_name
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

location: D:\Programs\Blender\2.79\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py:189



location: <unknown location>:-1
```

I don't know how to fix the error, I have even tried appending objects in a new file. But it shoes the same error. I am using Blender 2.9.

Looking forward to your answers

Comment: The trace shows something like a "history" of what went wrong. Python uses "None" to describe nonexistent/null/empty things. The last line indicates that the program tried to read the "name" attribute of an object, but failed because it was a "None" object (which has no "name" because it contains no data). Looking on the previous line, "tex.name = ..." attempts to write data into the "name" portion of "tex". From the error we got, this indicates the variable "tex" has no data.

Comment: To fix the problem, you might need to create a texture that the script can find or use. If you are using Blender Render, it could be your objects are don't have textures assigned to them (I'm not too familiar with that engine though).